# Recharts: Label content props is not working

Tags: reactjs, recharts

I am trying to make a custom label by passing a React Component to the content props of `Label` component and the label doesn't show.

My goal is to display the label at the center of a pie chart. Below is my code snippet and here is a working [sample](https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-issue-template-forked-sndl8h?file=/src/index.js).

```
<PieChart>
  <Pie
    isAnimationActive={false}
    data={pieArray}
    innerRadius={100}
    outerRadius={150}
    dataKey="value"
    cy="50%"
    cx="50%"
    startAngle={90}
    endAngle={-270}
  >
    {pieArray.map(({ data }, id) => (
      <Cell key={data} fill={chartColors[id % 8]} />
    ))}
    <Label
      content={<CustomLabel />}
      position="center"
    />
  </Pie>
</PieChart>
```

**Pie Chart**

```
function CustomLabel(props: any) {
  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="custom">Custom Label</h1>
      <p>Testing</p>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Custom Label**

I am using React version 17.0.2 and recharts 2.1.2. Link to [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/recharts-issue-template-forked-sndl8h?file=/src/index.js)  sample. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

try wrapping in **foreignObject**

```html
<foreignObject>
  <div>
    <h1 className="custom">Custom Label</h1>
    <p>Testing</p>
  </div>
</foreignObject>
```